# Integrate outlook 365 sign in in android application

Tags: android, office365, google-signin, office365api

I was working on an android application but for the sign in i need to sign in using outlook 365. I have tried using google+ sign in and it worked but there is no official documentation how to integrate through outlook 365. Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the following Microsoft's official MSDN documentation:

> [Understanding authentication with Office 365 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks)

In which you will find their sample project for Android at GitHub:

[Office 365 Connect Sample for Android](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Android-Connect)

> *To learn more about the sample, visit our [understanding the code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Android-Connect/wiki/Understanding-the-Connect-sample-code) wiki*
>   *page. If you just want to use this code sample in your app, visit the*
>   *[Using the O365 Android Connect sample code in your app](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Android-Connect/wiki/Using-the-O365-Android-Connect-sample-code-in-your-app).*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @BNK that really helped and saved a lot of time.